# Grails/GORM: Two domain classes with the same underlying table

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I want to do something sort of bad and I'm not sure if I can convince Grails to let me. I have a legacy table that stores historical student data, something like:

```
UserId | TermCode | Status | Other data
-------+----------+--------+-----------
1      | 2017     | A      | etc
1      | 2016     | S      | etc
1      | 2015     | A      | etc
2      | 2017     | A      | etc
...
```

The primary key is composite, consisting of userId and term. What I'd really like is to have two classes, something like:

```
class Student {
  Long userId
  static hasMany = [studentTerms: StudentTerm]
  static mapping = {
    table name: 'student'
    id name: 'userId' generator: 'assigned'
  }
}

class StudentTerm {
  Long userId
  String termCode
  String status
  ...
  static hasOne = [student: Student]
  static mapping = {
    table name: 'student'
    id composite: ['userId', 'termCode']
  }
}
```

This is so I can have another class with a "student" property that gives that class access to the entire history

When I try to do it this way (and use these classes in associations in other classes), Grails complains about there being the wrong number of elements to the primary key. It doesn't like that I'm defining two different classes to use the same table in two different ways. I imagine if I could create a view over the student table that would solve the issue for me but unfortunately that's not an option.

So is there a way to disable whatever checking is telling Grails/Hibernate that when I create an association to Student, it should be checking the definition of StudentTerm as well? Or is this too far outside the bounds of what GORM deems a reasonable database structure?

Comment: Why not a database migration that creates your student table and populates it with unique userId instances from the legacy 'student-term' table rather than trying to wrangle Gorm/Hibernate?

Comment: @railsdog Unfortunately that's not an option. I have to work with the tables I've got. Otherwise my job would be so much easier! :-)

Comment: What is the purpose of the Student class, as it basically just has an Id, and a list of StudentTerms?  All queries where you would use a student Id can still be used to retrieve StudentTerm objects, and that's all you'd get from a Student retrieval anyway.  i.e. what would you use the Student class for, that you can't do with just the StudentTerm class?

Comment: @billjamesdev That is a good question, and one I've been wrestling with. For a bit of background, I'm rewriting an existing library to be more Grails-y. The idea of having a `Student` class is to keep the new library interface as close to the old one as possible. If I can do that, great. Otherwise all the applications that use this library (which is almost all of the applications we support) will need to be retrofitted to support the new interface. This is also not the end of the world, but if I can keep the library backwards-compatible without committing any cardinal sins then that's ideal.